# Wait for a future function to complete its execution

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I am new to flutter and in my below code there is read data function is called at line 18(it performs Firebase Database operations) I want that the **readData()** function must complete its execution before going to the print statement(line 19) and further execution.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/SignInPage.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/UserProfile.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/dashboard.dart';

class AuthService  {
  bool flag = false;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users');

    handleAuth(){
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData) {
         readData();
          print(flag);
          if(flag ==true)
            return DashboardPage();
          else
            return UserProfile();
        }
        else {
          return SignIn();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> readData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final userid = user.uid;
    DBRef.child(userid).once().then((DataSnapshot data){
      print(userid);
      if(data.value!=null)
        {
          flag =  true;
          print(data.key);
          print(data.value);
        }
      else{
        print('User not found');
        flag = false;
      }
    });
  }

  signOut(){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  signIn(AuthCredential authCreds){
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
  }

  signInWithOTP(smsCode,verId){
    AuthCredential authCreds = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId,
        smsCode: smsCode
    );
    signIn(authCreds);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a future to complete inside a build/builder method then using `FutureBuilder` is a good way to go. This way you can set up a placeholder widget whilst the future is completing, and then once its done output the desired results. In the example below I've used a circular progress indicator as the placeholder but you could use any widget:

```dart
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: readData(),
        builder: (context, futureSnapshot) {
          if (!futureSnapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

          print(flag);
          if(flag ==true)
            return DashboardPage();
          else
            return UserProfile();
        }
      );
    }
    else {
      return SignIn();
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: So that means there's an issue in the `readData` function. It looks like it never returns, can you await `DBRef.child` and then insert a return statement `return Future.value()` below?

Comment: By returning Future.value the further code becomes dead code and again the Circular progress bar executed

Answer (score 0):

Since **readData()** is An **AsyncFunction** ,

Adding the keyword **await** before readData() , will force readData() to finish,and after that it will print , **However** you can't do it since StreamBuilder is waiting for Widget return type.

So what you can do is .
maybe modify your readData to return a **Future boolean** readData() ;

```
 Future<bool> readData() async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final userid = user.uid;
    DBRef.child(userid).once().then((DataSnapshot data){
      print(userid);
      if(data.value!=null)
        {
          print(data.key);
          print(data.value);
          return true;
         
        }
      else{
        print('User not found');
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

and you call it :

```
readData().then((value)
{
 if (value ==true)
return Widget
else
return Widget;

}
);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Error Comes on the Device Screen:
A build function returned null.
The Offending widget is:StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>Build functions must never return null.
To return empty space that cause the building widget to fill available room return "Container()"